# Access numeric indices in openCL vectors of size greater than 16

Tags: vector, opencl, indices

In Opencl for vector up to length 16 . we can access its (scalar) components by specifying them:

```
float16 x;
x.sA // refers to the 11th element of the float16 variable x
x.sF // refers to the 16th element of the float16 variable x
```

How can we access components of `float32 y` or `float128 w` .Is there an extension for that ?(I didn`t find that it is built-in)
as well I can combine indices:

```
float16 x;
float4 y = x.sB1AE
```

Is there something similar for vectors having length > 16 (or workaround)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently vector types with length >16 are not supported, but eventual support is being discussed.
As for now, use a linear array of type float and access components with

```
array[get_global_id(0)+get_global_size(0)*component]; // SoA: aaaabbbbccccddddeeee
```

Note that this way, memory access is a lot faster than with vector data types, as the Structure of Arrays (SoA) data layout enables coalesced memory access. Further you can choose an arbitrary number of components, let's say 15, and are not locked to choosing 2/3/4/8/16 with potentially extra memory allocation.

For comparison, the slower Array if Structures (AoS) layout would look like this:

```
array[get_global_id(0)*number_of_components+component]; // AoS: abcdeabcdeabcdeabcde
```

Comment: why vector types with length >16 are not supported?